# Changing text of text view repeatedly in an order

Tags: android, textview

I have three strings

```
String one="Connecting.";
String two="Connecting..";
String three="Connecting...";
```

I have a textView, what I want is to set text to textview in this order..
one-->two-->three-->one-->two-->three and so on until the process is completed.

I have done it in a for loop based on value i.e

```
if(value%3==0){
                            tx.setText(one);
                        }
                        else if(value%3==1){
                            tx.setText(two);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tx.setText(three);
                        }

This is done inside a thread and it is working well.
```

But I dont want to rely on "value".. I jst want that until process is completed the text changes in order as mentioned above.
I know it is vague but I am not getting how to do this.
Please if someone can give any hint.

```
    code:


 public void startProgress(View view) {

        bar.setProgress(0);
        tx.setText("Connect");
        new Thread(new Task()).start();
    }

    class Task implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                final int value = i;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            bar.setProgress(value);

                        String one="Connecting.";
                        String two="Connecting..";
                        String three="Connecting...";


                        if(value%3==0){
                            tx.setText(one);
                        }
                        else if(value%3==1){
                            tx.setText(two);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tx.setText(three);
                        }


                        }
                    });


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: are you using timer !

Comment: see Edited code.I m not using timer.

Comment: why you don't use progress bar , see this example http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/07/display-indeterminate-progress-bar-on.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense to have a counter like `value` that keeps incrementing. But you could do it a little more simply:

```
String[] texts = new String[3] {"Connecting.", "Connecting..", "Connecting..."};
int value = 0;

// ...

tx.setText(texts[value]);
value = (value+1)%3;
```

This way, you don't need your big messy `if` statement. You will need to find another way of notifying your thread when the job is done, rather than just having a fixed number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextSwitcher instead of TextView...It will work